# Get azure-pipelines.yml file to specific branch

Tags: azure-devops

I want my `Pipeline` to work on a specific branch, different than `master`. After building `Pipeline` in `DevOps` the `azure-pipelines.yml` file goes to the `master` branch. Do I have to add this file manually to a different branch? Or it can be done somewhere during a configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default its being added to master branch, you'd need to cherry pick it into your desired branch, or just create it\edit it there in the first place. its just a file.

Comment: I've noticed that placing the file in the branch doesn't make it automatically show in the view to run. What am I missing?

Comment: please, create a new question with specific details and link it here in the comments